# How to use core Java classes in Papyrus UML (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, class-diagram

I'm new to Papyrus UML in Eclipse. I'm trying to make a class diagram of classes that also use standard Java classes (e.g. java.awt.Point). So for example: **Class Tracker** has a property **Point location**. However, if I click the property **location**, I cannot set its type to any standard Java class.

I tried *Import from registered library* but there are no options that include the standard Java packages.

How can I use these standard classes in my class diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Papyrus with Java existing java code. Usually you model then generate a java code from the model.
You can try the reverse engineering feature but it would create model which is now not related to your existing java class.

The only solution I see is to use live code and model synchronization UML tool.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That kind of sucks. I don't have any existing code yet and I want to figure out how my classes should look, but now it turns out that I cannot model my classes with core Java properties? -1 for UML.

Comment: UML 2 is just amazing and if you look well at its structure it is exactly as java. I mean you have project, then packages inside which you create your model element. The problem is the modeling tool philosophy and features which remained the same in the last 15 years !!

Answer (score 1):

Some Papyrus/Java lover should write the core java profile and donate it to the papyrus project.

Comment: I tried posting on their forum but it is moderated.. so basically cannot contribute until one of the mods approves. Not sure how else to give them my solution.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, i found a way..

Simply download the Java Core (JCL) API UML file I made here:

https://mega.nz/#!qVdAAAIL!gWstAOCyQFWVHTqxVrgnYssiOJZSAEN-rbxMIaZzMJo

And use the model->import->import package from user model functionality in papyrus in eclipse

[image: eclipse import package papyrus]

Then you can use standard java library types outside of just primitives in your papyrus UML diagram.

I've tested this with the code generator and it works with one caveat, you end up with an extra local copy of the standard library packages in the generated project. Simply delete these and you can move on with your day. I'm not sure, but eclipse payprus codegen doesn't currently seem to generate the imports necessary, so you'll have to do that manually or let the IDE do it for you, but it sure beats having placeholder types.

If you're wondering how this was done, I used the following plugin:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jar2uml

To generate a UML file for the standard library jar file version **1.8**, this is usually under the jre installation directory inside the **lib** folder.

This gave me a model with all the standard library packages within it, but the model was named rt.java.* instead of java.* which messed with the code generation process. So i simply removed the other packages other than java.* and made java the model itself instead of a package.

Answer (score 0):

There is a java profile and library/package in Papyrus Software Designer extention.
You may install it via the market place.
See also: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_Code_Generation